# Populate POJO with array (root JSON node) using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, jackson

I'm using Jackson and RESTEasy to hook into an external API. The API mainly returns simple objects which I have managed to successfully populate into POJOs.

I'm hitting a problem where I get an array of objects back e.g.

```
[
  {
    "variable1": "someValue1",
    "variable2": "someValue2",
    "variable3": "someValue3"
  }
  {
    "variable1": "someValue4",
    "variable2": "someValue5",
    "variable3": "someValue6"
  }
  {
    "variable1": "someValue7",
    "variable2": "someValue8",
    "variable3": "someValue9"
  }
]
```

I have 2 classes: one called VariableObject which looks like this:

```
public class VariableObject {

    private String variable1;
    private String variable2;
    private String variable3;

}
```

and VariableResponse which looks like:

```
public class VariableResponse {

    private List<VariableObject> variableObjects;

}
```

My client uses JAXRS Response class to read the entity into the class i.e

```
 return response.readEntity(VariableResponse.class);
```

I get a stack trace which reads:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of VariableResponse out of START_ARRAY token
```

I understand you can return these as a List of POJOs i.e List quite easily, but this is not what I want to do.

The question really is two parts:
 a. Can I possibly populate the VariableResponse POJO using Jackson (some how) preferably without a customer deserialiser? Maybe some annotation exists (this would be ideal)?
 b. Is there some way to detect if an Array is being retuned as the root JSON node in the response and then act accordingly?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I answered before reading the full question ...

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is indeed an array of objects.

You can deserialize it with:

```
response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<VariableObject>>() {});
```

And then create a new instance of VariableResponse passing resulting List as a constructor parameter like this:

```
public class VariableResponse {

   private final List<VariableObject> variableObjects;

   public VariableResponse(List<VariableObject> variableObjects) {
      this.variableObject = new ArrayList<>(variableObjects);
   }
}
```

Comment: While this does work, it isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'd ideally like to pass in a class to the response when reading the entity. e.g. response.readEntity(myObject.getClass()); - in this case that class would be VariableResponse. I don't really want to instantiate it separately. The alternative would be if there was a way to detect that the response entity was an array of JSON Objects. If that's possible?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't able to do that. You need to have a key to deserialize a field in your POJO. JSON array doesn't have a key to bind to. The two just don't map one to another logically.

Now, if you have any control over the back-end system you are talking to, you can add a key to the JSON array like this: { "variableObjects" : [...] } but I presume you can't do that, right?

Comment: Sadly not (otherwise I probably would change a few things I don't like :)). Could it be done by putting a customer deserialiser on the POJO? Think I'm starting to favour that using Jackson's annotations.

Comment: You can use a custom converter of course but this is something I personally would advise against if the call in question is being made once throughout the codebase. And I'm assuming you don't actually want to write one either.

Answer (score 1):

You might forget to add comma after each `{..}`. After correcting your JSON string, I converted it into `ArrayList<VariableObject>` using `TypeReference` and `ObjectMapper`.

sample code:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
...
TypeReference<ArrayList<VariableObject>> typeRef = new TypeReference<ArrayList<VariableObject>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    ArrayList<VariableObject> data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
    for (VariableObject var: data) {
            System.out.println(var.getVariable1()+","+var.getVariable2()+","+var.getVariable3());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

output:

```
someValue1,someValue2,someValue3
someValue4,someValue5,someValue6
someValue7,someValue8,someValue9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer your own response type direct.

Try just extending ArrayList?

```
public VariableResponse extends ArrayList<VariableObject> {

}
```